# Why we call adding a listener to button directly as inner class?

Tags: java, class, inner-classes

If we add event listener to a button in java like this :

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

public void onClick(View v)
{
// Do smoething
}

});
```

this is called we are using inner-class, I have problem in understanding the the concept of inner class

isn't the inner class declared like this ?

```
    class AOuter{
    int a=5;

     class BInner{
       // do smothing
     }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The click listener is an *anonymous* inner class, the other one is simply an inner class. They are both types of [nested classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

Comment: +1 But they're both inner classes, OP was right in that respect.

Comment: Good, but why we till call it a class despite we are using 'new', aren't we creating an object here ?!

Comment: Yes, we are creatng a new object but that object's class is a new class. We are subclassing `OneClicklistener` and can even add new methods - thus its a new class.

Comment: @Andrejs sorry for spamming you, maybe ! . but what do you mean in object's class is a new class ??

Comment: If you do `new Object();` it just creates new object, if you do `new Object(){...}` you've effectively have subclassed `Object` class and created new class where you can define new methods/fields.

Comment: @Andrejs You are very awesome, now I got it :) .. please do you have a reference to learn more about these ??

Comment: The official Java docs are a good start http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html

Answer (score 0):

The class you have provided to setOnClickListener cannot be instantiated elsewhere. It lives just as an argument to that function while the class defined in the second code segment is nested and it can be instantiated normally.

Answer (score 0):

@Andrejs is correct. The reason for people using anonymous inner class to add the listener usually is because this is a one time thing and you won't reuse that action/listener. However, if that listener/action is planned to be reused, one should explicitly define it to make it reusable.